# How can I select all the divs inside a section tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a turn-based game in javascript. I want to move the player from div to div. I have put all those divs in a section and then into an array using queryselectorall. Now my problem is that I also have another divs who I want to use and I can't select them separately. Can anyone tell me how to select only some divs? I have seen something like section>div to differentiate them, but that doesn't work for me.

I have tried replacing div with span on rollDice, zar1, and zar2, but by doing that some CSS breaks.

```
~
<div class="rollDice">Roll the dice</div>
<div class="zar1">
    <img src="poze/dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice" id="dice-1" style="width:150px">
</div>

<div class="zar2">
    <img src="poze/dice-5.png" alt="Dice" class="dice2" id="dice-2"  style="width:150px">
</div>


<section class="mutari">
    <div class="nr1 mutabil"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="nr2 mutabil"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="nr3 mutabil"><h1>3</h1></div>
</section>
~
```

I want to select the div only from the section. And after that I want to select the first 3 divs.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you provide a [example] of the HTML structure that is giving you problems, indicating which ones you want to select and which ones not?

Comment: Ok then. I'll give a bit more of the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
document.querySelectorAll('section > div:nth-child(-n+3)')
```

`section` (a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors)) finds your `<section>`. If you had more section elements, you could use `section.mutari` to be more precise (using a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)).

`> div` selects all the `<div>` tags that are direct children of that section. `>` is a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator).

`:nth-child(-n+3)`, a [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), restricts this to only select the first three elements, not all of them. It is not needed in your example, as you only have three divs; but if you had more, this would give you only the first three.

Comment: this is not what he asked for! He asked how to select only some specific divs. With the solution of @trinity and me you get that result in a dynamic way! Yours isnt really stable as if he adds new divs he needs to search a new solution!

Comment: @PatrickLüthi Please demonstrate where OP says they need a live collection. On the contrary, `querySelectorAll` was mentioned; OP just didn't know how to construct a good selector.

Comment: "Can anyone tell me how to select only some divs?" with this question your answer is wrong. He says that he needs only some divs, not the first three or anything (I know currently that works but maybe later not, and why not do it the correct way from the start). With my solution he is able to pick exactly the divs he needs and if he adds more divs it will still work! In Javascript you should always programm dynamic way. Here is an artical that helps you learn more about it: https://medium.com/@hernang87/simple-dynamic-programming-example-91a0074f55fc

Comment: @PatrickLüthi "I want to select the div only from the section. And after that I want to select the first 3 divs." Please don't imagine things that are not there, and respond to things that are.

Comment: If you answer to me why not read my answer first? No need to drag comments that long. I explained why in the correct way. Just accept it. ;)

Comment: thank you both for helping. The combination of both your answers helped me get to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

With `document.body.childNodes`

Just replace document.body with your HTML Element.
You can filter after that through the list you get an select all divs.

If you want to get all divs you can also use following:

```
var dh = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Comment: How does this tell OP "how to select only some divs" as they asked?

Comment: after that you can take the list and filter through. Select the ones you need by name or id. Exactly how i descriebed it.

Answer (score 1):

Get all div nodes:

Use                `document.body.getElementsByTagName('div')`

**Or**

Get filtered div nodes:

Take array from `document.body.childNodes`.

filter by using for loop and if condition.

Condition Example: use like `node[i].nodeName` and `node[i].id`

Comment: How does this tell OP "how to select only some divs" as they asked?

Comment: Take array from document.body.childNodes. And filter by using for loop and condition of node[i] .nodeName and node[i].id